Browser errors were logged to the console - Wordpress
I am checking my website in google pagespeed. I am getting following error. Any idea how to sort it out.
Thanks.
Errors logged to the console indicate unresolved problems. They can come from network request failures and other browser concerns. 

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at blob:

On the console, i have got it.
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.4.1
30Chrome is moving towards a new experience that allows users to choose to browse without third-party cookies.

I am clueless. Anyone can suggest where to start.
